# How to block custom post type listing page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I am working on WordPress site and having a problem with custom post type functionality. I have created a post type with the name "cust_team" and permalink is set to Post Name:

> Post Name : http://example.com/mytheme/sample-post/

Now when I am viewing "http://example.com/mytheme/cust_team" page it shows me a list of all the "cust_team" posts. But when I am viewing http://example.com/mytheme/post or page it redirects to 404 page. I just want to block the custom post type listing page, because its creating duplicate content issue in SEO.

Here is my register post type array::

```
$cpt_args['cust_team'] = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'              => esc_html__('Team Member','mytheme'),
        'singular_name'     => esc_html__('Team Member','mytheme'),
        'add_new'           => esc_html__('Add Team Member','mytheme'),
        'add_new_item'      => esc_html__('Add Team Member','mytheme'),
        'edit_item'         => esc_html__('Edit Team Member','mytheme'),
        'new_item'          => esc_html__('New Team Member','mytheme'),
        'all_items'       => esc_html__( 'All Team Members','mytheme'),
        'not_found'         => esc_html__('No Team Member found','mytheme'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => esc_html__('No Team Member found in Trash','mytheme'),
        'menu_name'                 => esc_html__('Team Members','mytheme'),
    ),
    'description'       => 'Manage Team Content.',
    'public'                => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'supports'              => array(
    'title',
    'thumbnail',
    'editor',
    'page-attributes',
    'custom-fields'
    ),
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-post',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => '',
    'capability_type'   => 'post',
    'map_meta_cap'          => true,
    'rewrite'               => array('slug'  => 'cust_team'),
);
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. I want to remove custom post type listing page like default post types "post" and "page" do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set `'has_archive' => false` and `'rewrite' => false`.

**has_archive**

> (boolean or string) (optional) Enables post type archives. Will use
>   $post_type as archive slug by default. Default: false
>
> Note: Will generate the proper rewrite rules if rewrite is enabled.
>   Also use rewrite to change the slug used. If string, it should be
>   translatable.

**rewrite**

> (boolean or array) (optional)
>
> Triggers the handling of rewrites for this post type. To prevent
>   rewrites, set to false.
>
> Default: true and use $post_type as slug

Note:

**If registering a post type inside of a plugin, call flush_rewrite_rules() in your activation and deactivation hook (see Flushing Rewrite on Activation below). If flush_rewrite_rules() is not used, then you will have to manually go to Settings > Permalinks and refresh your permalink structure before your custom post type will show the correct structure.**

I hope it will help you.

Comment: after setting "rewrite" to false, it's worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the following to false:

```
'has_archive' => false
```

You can read more about post types in [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: I tried this and after this saved permalinks again to flush the rewrite rules, but it's not working for me.